# Open source code coverage libraries for JDK7?

Tags: java, code-coverage, java-7

It seems like both Cobertura and Emma are outdated now. They don't cope with Java 7 byte code. Running instrumented tests with Cobertura results in verification errors

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 41 in method .....
```

A shame really because Cobertura really is cool and well-supported. For Java 6 byte code that is. But now I'm looking for a replacement. Preferably having both Maven and Jenkins support.

Are there any people in here using a code coverage library for Java 7 byte code ?

Comment: Are you focused on handling Java 7, or on open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) will do the job

Comment: That's quick ! :-) I was just looking to it. You are successfully using it in a Maven/Jenkins build ?

Comment: I mean a multi-module Maven project. Cobertura kept the modules strictly separated. As a result the integration tests were not measured correctly.

Comment: I don't use Maven, I'm afraid. There is a Jenkins plugin for it released a few weeks ago. I haven't got around to trying it yet, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: It looks like Jacoco is a nice alternative. Hence this is the answer I was looking for. BUT... in the meantime there's a workaround for this problem. Add -XX:-UseSplitVerifier to the jvm properties. It uses the previous version of the verifier.